# Errors of the Manifest

Tags: android, android-layout

i am new in working on android studio and while i am trying to write simple TTS code this errors appeared. how can i solve them?  See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: your missing a slash at the end of your action /> your missing '/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" >
```

to

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Fix XML closing in `action` tag :

`<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />`

You forgot the slash at the end: `/>`